# How do I update my flask API code deployed over uWSGI and Nginx on ubuntu?

Tags: python, api, ubuntu, nginx, flask

I followed the guide to set up my api here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

It works great and I can now make queries against my api succesfully. My issue is that now I want to tweak my flask app/api to do slightly different things and add functionality but the API i am pinging seems to be the old one, despite having updated the flask .py file on the server from my ssh. I tried going through all the steps in the tutorial i got it working with in the hopes of refreshing which code it accesses but nothing seems to work. Some of these commands I tried are:

```
sudo nginx -t

sudo service nginx restart
```

How can i do this and ping the updated flask .py file?

As per nos's suggestion i tried:

```
restart myproject
```

But this gave the following error:

```
restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=1000 pid=2596 comm="restart thonapi ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are restarting Nginx but not uwsgi. Nginx is just a proxy server that is routing requests to wsgi app. when you change in config of Nginx then these commands would work. but when changes are in wsgi app you have to restart service of uwsgi.

You could restart service by following commands. It depends what init system service is using

If service uses systemd system.

`sudo systemctl restart myproject`

Else if it uses upstart script.

`sudo restart myproject`

If all fails you can use or if you don't know about the init system being used:

`sudo service restart myproject`

Comment: this gave the following error: Failed to restart myproject.service: No such method 'RestartUnit' but i got it working via a sudo restart myproject

Comment: @majorcoder I missed the part that tutorial you followed was using upstart as init system. I've updated my answer for all types of systems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the service you created for this application. 
The docs you link to have a "Create an Upstart Script" section which I assume you have done. This runs your application like a service and you need to restart that service with the command:

```
restart myproject
```

(Or whichever name you gave instead of "myproject")

Comment: thank you. i tried this but it gave the following error: restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.8" (uid=1000 pid=2596 comm="restart thonapi ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")

Comment: System related admin tasks almost always need to be done as root, so try sudo restart myproject

Comment: adding sudo did it!